# how to bind inputmethodservice to an application in android

Tags: android, keyboard

Hi friends
I had created my own custom keyboard using inputmethodservice now i want to use it in my
application as a default keyboard.At the same time it could not be the default keyboard 
for other application that are running on my android mobile

Answer (score 1):

In short : you can not automatically select a specific inputmethodservice. This is a security feature in android (an inputmethodservice can potentially capture password and fill forms on user's behalf).

The only way to switch input method is to present a standardized InputMethod selection dialog to the user and let him choose (see [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html)'s [showInputMethodPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#showInputMethodPicker%28%29) function). Note that this choice is permanent and will affect the whole system.

If you need an application specific keyboard, you would better extend KeyboardView instead of inputmethodservice.